# When to use handler.post() & when to new Thread()

Tags: android, android-handler, android-thread

I'm wondering when should I use `handler.post(runnable);` and when should I use 
`new Thread(runnable).start();`

It is mentioned in developers documentation for Handler:

> Causes the Runnable r to be added to the message queue. The runnable
>   will be run on the thread to which this handler is attached.

Does this mean if I write in the `onCreate()` of `Activity` class:

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.post(runnable);
```

then runnable will be called in a separate thread or in the Activity's thread?

Comment: Never use `new Thread(runnable).start()`, you can run out of VM Stack Memory Size. You want to use `Executors` and store a reference to that (don't create a new executor per each call that would go to a background thread)

Answer (score 106, accepted):

You should use `Handler.post()` whenever you want to do operations on the UI thread.

So let's say you want to change a `TextView`'s text in the callback. Because the callback is not running on the UI thread, you should use `Handler.post()`.

In Android, as in many other UI frameworks, UI elements (widgets) can be only modified from UI thread.

Also note that the terms "UI thread" and "main thread" are often used interchangeably.

---

Edit: an example of the long-running task:

```
mHandler = new Handler();

new Thread(new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run () {
    // Perform long-running task here
    // (like audio buffering).
    // You may want to update a progress
    // bar every second, so use a handler:
    mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
     @Override
     public void run () {
       // make operation on the UI - for example
       // on a progress bar.
     }
    });
  }
}).start();
```

Of course, if the task you want to perform is really long and there is a risk that user might switch to some another app in the meantime, you should consider using a [Service](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html).

Comment: But if say I want to buffer an audio stream from internet. Should I do it via handler.post or by new Thread?

Comment: Really depends on your requirements. I would consider either a new thread or a Service. I'll update the answer with example in a sec.

Comment: "The explanation is wrong on many levels. – T.Dimitrov"  ? 
Really? Absolutely unsubstantiated and useless comment. Where is your proves?

Comment: @T.Dimitrov you might want to be more explicit about what exactly is wrong with the explanation here, otherwise no one else will know what you mean.

Answer (score 38):

To answer you specific question:

> Does this mean if in the onCreate of Activity class I write:
>
> Handler handler = new Handler() hanlder.post(runnable); then, runnable
>   will be called in a separate thread or on the Activity's thread?

No it won't be. The Runnable will be called on the Main Thread itself.
Handler is simply used for posting a message to the thread to which it is attached (where its is created).
It does not create a thread on its own.
In your example, you created a Handler in the main Thread (that where Activity.OnCreate() is called) and hence any message posted on such a Handler will be run on the Main Thread only.

Comment: Right answers are not always the selected as best. Thanks

Comment: You just changed completely the perfs of my app!! Moving from handler to thread just made my app flying! So big thanks man!!

Answer (score 12):

Example is jacked:

```
mHandler = new Handler();
new Thread(new Runnable(){
  @Override
  public void run () {
    mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
     @Override
     public void run () {
       mUiView.setX(x);
     }
    });
  }
}).start();
```

Alternatively you can skip the handler and use the post method on the view directly:

```
new Thread(new Runnable(){
  @Override
  public void run () {
    mUiView.post(new Runnable() {
     @Override
     public void run () {
       mUiView.setX(x);
     }
    });
  }
}).start();
```

This is a good post that outlines the difference: [What exactly does the post method do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840007/what-exactly-does-the-post-method-do)

Answer (score 8):

use `handler.post()` when you want to **post** the code *(usually from background thread)* to the **main thread**. Yea, POST,just like you, post a letter to someone. With the help of *handler* the code will be executed ASAP i.e. almost immediately.