# What are Handlers and Runnables for in Android?

Tags: android, kotlin

Please I am blocked with this concept of Handlers and Runnables in Android. Can someone please give me detailed explanation on Handlers and Runnables? Their syntax and implementation? I have read many articles on this but the concepts are not still clear and are even deployed in Java. Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15136199/when-to-use-handler-post-when-to-new-thread . Whether it is Java or Kotlin isn't relevant.

Answer (score 5):

I'm going to try to simplify so bear with me if it is not 100% accurate.

Basically, a Handler is used to communicate with a `MessageQueue` associated with a  `Thread`.
If you're on the main thread, or if you've called `Looper.prepare()` in the `Thread` that you're in, it has a `Looper` which is basically a holder for the `MessageQueue`.

This queue is constantly polled so that whenever a `Message` goes into it, it's dealt with on the Thread associated with this `MessageQueue`

If you're trying to execute a piece of code on a particular `Thread`, you have to use a `Runnable`. It is just an interface that has a `void run()` method which will be executed by the Looper, on its `Thread`.

Let's say you're doing a network request, you want it to happen on another `Thread` but when you get the result you somehow need to pass the data back to the `Main Thread` in order to update your UI because `View`s can't be modified from another `Thread`.
You would do it like so:

```
// This will let you run method on main thread (even if you're not on main thread)
private final Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());

// This will let you run method on background thread
private final Executor executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();


public void doSomething() {
    // posting to executor will go to background thread
    executor.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // This will now run on background thread
            // you can for example do network request here

            // posting to handler will go back to main thread
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // This will execute on the Main Thread
                }
            });
        }
   });
}
```

Comment: Totally impressed that you took this question on and provided an answer that, if not exhaustive, is undoubtedly useful.  Well done.

Comment: I am more than grateful for the effort  and time that you have used to clarify the used of these concepts. from here, I must be able to find my way. Thanks once more