# Delay when drawer is being closed on loading a fragment with a lot of data

Tags: android, android-fragments

On my fragments that are not loading a lot of data they load very quickly and the drawer closes quick.

However when loading a fragment with a lot of data there is a delay when drawer is closed.

I have setup a progress bar on the main layout to show and put the data loading into a view.post(new Runnable() but the drawer still has a delay when closing. Maybe im not doing something right?

on the fragments OnCreateView method i have this

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_icon_request_list, container, false);

    if (view != null) {
        progressBar = (ProgressBar) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.base_progressSpinner);
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        view.post(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    initCards();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
    return view;
}
```

initCards() is the method doing all the work. There is no work being done on onCreate or onActivityCreated

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe this link can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13840315/1276374 - portion about    View.post(new Runnable(..))

Comment: if you post a runnable like this it will still run on the UI Thread. What you have to do is do the work in a separate thread. If you post your initCards()  code I can help you.

Comment: updated post with the initCards() method

Answer (score 0):

you can try using delay , like below :

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        initCard();
    }
}, 1000);
```