# Why i need call view.postRunnable to show keyboard

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

I have an logic like this: when enter the edit activity, i will show popup first, then show soft keyboard in the onDismissListener callback, but when i call *showKeyboard* directly in the callback, the soft keyboard doesn't show. Only i call the `view.postRunnable`, it will show as expected. As well the activity softkeyboard option is set `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize"`

```
private void showKeyboard() {
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)
            getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.showSoftInput(mEditText, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
}
```

Comment: check out this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840007/what-exactly-does-the-post-method-do

Answer (score 1):

Unless someone with deep knowledge of the inner gears of the UI framework come by to answer, everyone's answer will be a "best guess". So below is my best guess:

That is most likely related to the [`Window`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Window.html) and [`WindowManager`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.html) and how they interact with `Views` and keyboards.

The `EditText` being passed to the method have a token to your activity window, and here is my guess:

If the window is not in foreground, it can't show a keyboard. So when you `post` the method call, then that method gets executed after the Window from the Popup is gone, and the Window from the activity is in Foreground.

Answer (score 0):

The `onDismiss()` callback is most likely called from non-UI thread, so you can't update your UI directly. That's why you need to post it to the UI thread with `view.postRunnable()`.