# Android App Crashing after calling method in a thread?

Tags: java, android

Currently in my Android Game there is a simple thread that runs, decreasing a horizontal progressbar by 1 every X milliseconds. I'm trying to implement a method so when the progressbar hits 0, a TextView changes to "Game Over". **The app crashes whenever this function is called in this way**. I have also initialized the variable correctly so the method should have no trouble seeing this TextView.

```html
    public class MyThread extends Thread{
        @Override
        public void run(){
            while (counter > 0 && keepRunning){
                counter = counter - 1;
                android.os.SystemClock.sleep(calculateSleepTick());
                mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        progressTest.setProgress(counter);
                    }
                });
            }
            isGameOver();
        }
    }
```

```html
    public void isGameOver(){
        scoreText.setText("Game Over");
    }
```

Comment: If there is a crash then there is a corresponding Logcat entry - please share this as well

Comment: Any logs will be helpful..

Comment: Try using a handler - https://stackoverflow.com/a/13840315/2308683

Comment: You cannot update UI components other than UI thread. To update UI you need to post the data into UI/main thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot update UI in non UI threads. Call `isGameOver()` this way.

`runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
      isGameOver();
    }
  });`

Comment: Ah thanks man. Where would I implement this. Do I have to create a new object or?

Comment: https://www.intertech.com/Blog/android-non-ui-to-ui-thread-communications-part-1-of-5/

Answer (score 2):

Your isGameOver function sets the text of a UI element.  You can't call functions of UI elements on a thread other than main.  It needs to be posted to the UI thread to do that.

Comment: That makes sense. What can I google or research so I can fix this?

Comment: Your code already shows how to do it-  you post to a UI thread handler to set the progress level.