# What does RecyclerView.post do?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I am new to android development. I came across a project in kotlin where post was used in RecyclerView.

```
recyclerView?.post { layoutManager?.scrollToPosition(MainActivity.currentPosition) }
```

Can anyone please explain what is the use of post in the above case? Thanks in advance

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13840315/7972699

read this

Comment: Thanks for the link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sends a `Runnable` to the `Handler` object that is associated with the `recyclerView`.

If you aren't familiar with `Handler`, it is one way to execute code on another thread.
When you run on a secondary thread, and want to come back to the apps main UI thread, you can use a post method, pass a runnable, and it will run on the main thread.

***Note:*** Handlers can exist on **other** threads as well.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question. When does the `Recyclerview` call the `Runnable` you passed?