# How to set the bottomsheet peek height to below a view?

Tags: java, android, bottom-sheet, bottom-sheet-behavior

I have a `bottomsheet behavior` in a `linear layout`. I need to set the `peak height` of the `bottom sheet` to below this `button`, so it works great on all screens instead of giving a constant value.

The `bottom sheet` is inside a `CoordinatorLayout` that has that weird transparent big space. I want the sheet to fill up that space
The rounded bottom sheet's `peak height` should match up to below the Fireworks text

[image]

I have tried with `setPeekHeight(ContainerOfBottomSheet.getMeasuredHeight());` but it seems to return 0 or an extremely big value.
How can I do that?

**UPDATE**
This is my code:

```java
    private void SettingSheet(LinearLayout sheet, final CoordinatorLayout c) {
      final BottomSheetBehavior beh = BottomSheetBehavior.from(sheet);
        
      c.measure(ActionBar.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ActionBar.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
      CHeight = c.getMeasuredHeight();
        
      beh.setPeekHeight(CHeight);
            }
```

//This is making the big value I have talked about.

Comment: post your code!

Comment: Could you prepare some picture that so your idea? Maybe that could help.

Comment: @TrầnĐứcTâm I already posted an image

Comment: post your xml file too

Comment: I guest you problem is you set the peek height before the CordinatorLayout done it measure task. Let try the `post` method of the view. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840007/what-exactly-does-the-post-method-do

Comment: @TrầnĐứcTâm I've tried with the post method, but it hasnt worked

Answer (score 0):

You can set the peek height of a BottomSheet to a specific view using the setPeekHeight method of the BottomSheetBehavior class. Here's an example:

```
ViewTreeObserver vto = target_view.getViewTreeObserver();
    vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            target_view.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);

            // Get the height of the target view from the top of its parent view
            int targetViewHeight = target_view.getTop();
            // Set the peek height of the BottomSheet to the height of the target view
            bottomSheetBehavior.setPeekHeight(targetViewHeight);
            // Set the state of the BottomSheet to collapsed
            bottomSheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED);

        }
    });
```